# Google Maps V2 with strange logcat error Failed to load map

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

So I tried to implemented a map fragment in my app. The application works perfectly on my Galaxy S4, but wont work on my Xperia Z. The fragment shows up blank, with no map. And LogCat states:

```
07-31 00:20:07.265: E/Google Maps Android API(8763): Failed to load map. Error contacting
Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network   errors).
```

So I checked if the Google-play-services_lib was referenced correct, and I do think so. All permissions are OK, and everything should work fine. (I assume the authentication problem si bogus since its working on the S4?).

I then checked logcat without filter and I get spammed with text making no sense:

```
07-31 00:23:45.398: E/LocSvc_adapter(705): I/<--- void globalEventCb(locClientHandleType, uint32_t, locClientEventIndUnionType, void*) line 89 QMI_LOC_EVENT_POSITION_REPORT_IND_V02
07-31 00:23:45.438: E/LocSvc_adapter(705): I/<--- void globalEventCb(locClientHandleType, uint32_t, locClientEventIndUnionType, void*) line 89 QMI_LOC_EVENT_NMEA_IND_V02
07-31 00:23:45.438: E/LocSvc_eng(705): I/<=== nmea_cb line 1681 0x74211aa0
07-31 00:23:45.448: E/LocSvc_adapter(705): I/<--- void globalEventCb(locClientHandleType, uint32_t, locClientEventIndUnionType, void*) line 89 QMI_LOC_EVENT_NMEA_IND_V02
07-31 00:23:45.448: E/LocSvc_eng(705): I/<=== nmea_cb line 1681 0x7331d878
07-31 00:23:45.458: E/LocSvc_adapter(705): I/<--- void globalEventCb(locClientHandleType, uint32_t, locClientEventIndUnionType, void*) line 89 QMI_LOC_EVENT_NMEA_IND_V02
07-31 00:23:45.458: E/LocSvc_eng(705): I/<=== nmea_cb line 1681 0x74211aa0
07-31 00:23:45.458: E/LocSvc_adapter(705): I/<--- void globalEventCb(locClientHandleType, uint32_t, locClientEventIndUnionType, void*) line 89 QMI_LOC_EVENT_NMEA_IND_V02
07-31 00:23:45.458: E/LocSvc_eng(705): I/<=== nmea_cb line 1681 0x74211aa0
07-31 00:23:45.478: E/LocSvc_adapter(705): I/<--- void globalEventCb(locClientHandleType, uint32_t, locClientEventIndUnionType, void*) line 89 QMI_LOC_EVENT_NMEA_IND_V02
07-31 00:23:45.478: E/LocSvc_eng(705): I/<=== nmea_cb line 1681 0x7331d878
07-31 00:23:45.478: E/LocSvc_adapter(705): I/<--- void globalEventCb(locClientHandleType, uint32_t, locClientEventIndUnionType, void*) line 89 QMI_LOC_EVENT_NMEA_IND_V02
07-31 00:23:45.478: E/LocSvc_eng(705): I/<=== nmea_cb line 1681 0x7331d878
07-31 00:23:45.488: E/LocSvc_adapter(705): I/<--- void globalEventCb(locClientHandleType, uint32_t, locClientEventIndUnionType, void*) line 89 QMI_LOC_EVENT_GNSS_SV_INFO_IND_V02
07-31 00:23:45.488: E/LocSvc_afw(705): I/<=== sv_status_cb - line 1043 14
```

And it just keeps on going like this. I can't make any sense out of it. If I remove everything related to maps, the error stops. So its something with the Google maps which trigger the error.  Here is the classes containing the Gmaps code:

The .java file:

```
package com.nordoid.tracephone;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class Mfragment_main extends Fragment 
{
    TextView settings;
    TextView home;
    TextView friends;
    final int RQS_GooglePlayServices = 1;
    MapFragment myMapFragment;
    private GoogleMap map;
        
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
 
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
 
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mainmenu_main, container, false);
        
        map  = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map1)).getMap();
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        setUpMap();
            
                                    /*** Statiske posisjoner til MAPS ***/
        
        final LatLng Pune = new LatLng(58.341907, 8.584957);
         @SuppressWarnings("unused")
         Marker pune = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                   .position(Pune)
                                   .title("Friend 1")
                                   .snippet("Christian")
                                   .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));     
         
         final LatLng Pune1 = new LatLng(58.421157,7.400101);
         @SuppressWarnings("unused")
         Marker pune1 = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                   .position(Pune1)
                                   .title("Friend 2")
                                   .snippet("Howie")
                                   .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_VIOLET)));
         
         final LatLng Pune2 = new LatLng(36.724576,-4.452317);
         @SuppressWarnings("unused")
         Marker pune2 = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                   .position(Pune2)
                                   .title("Christian på ferie!")
                                   .snippet("Partyyløva.")
                                   .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));    
        return view; 
    }
    
    private void setUpMap() 
    {
        // Enable MyLocation Layer of Google Map
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Get LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Create a criteria object to retrieve provider
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        // Get the name of the best provider
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        // Get Current Location
        Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        // Get latitude of the current location
        double latitude = 60.0426;//myLocation.getLatitude();

        // Get longitude of the current location
        double longitude = 6.3286;//myLocation.getLongitude();

        // Create a LatLng object for the current location
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);      

        // Show the current location in Google Map        
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        // Zoom in the Google Map
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(3));
        
//      map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("You are here!"));
    }
    
}
```

The .xml file :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/slider"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.32" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="216dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="381dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="83dp"
            android:background="@drawable/inputfield"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingTop="0dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:paddingLeft="7dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="QUICK TRACK"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#33b5e5" />

            <SearchView
                android:id="@+id/searchView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:paddingLeft="-15dp" >

            </SearchView>

        </RelativeLayout>
 
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="113dp"
            android:background="@drawable/inputfield" >

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/map1"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And my manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.nordoid.tracephone"
    android:versionCode="9"
    android:versionName="1.1.45" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="13"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
    
    <permission
     android:name="com.nordroid.tracephone.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
     android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
     
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.nordroid.tracephone.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/> 
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>


    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.network"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        >
         
           <activity android:name="com.nordoid.tracephone.install.MainInstaller"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" 
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged"
            >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
         </activity>
    
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.nordoid.tracephone.Settings"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.nordoid.tracephone.MainMenu"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" 
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.nordoid.tracephone.background.ReceiveSMS2VideoActivityHidden"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.someName" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.nordoid.tracephone.background.CameraActivityHidden"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.someName2" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.nordoid.tracephone.FriendList"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.someName2" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.nordoid.tracephone.googleplay"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.someName2" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.nordoid.tracephone.Friend"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.someName2" />
        <activity android:name="com.nordoid.tracephone.background.CameraPreviewHidden" >
             
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.tapfortap.TapForTapActivity" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.nordoid.tracephone.background.hidden_gps_and_mail"
            android:enabled="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="intent.action.HIDDEN_GPS_AND_MAIL" >
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.nordoid.tracephone.background.ReceiveSMS"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="1000" >
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.nordoid.tracephone.background.ReceiveSMS2"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="1000" >
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="THE MAPS API KEY"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I am aware of the horrible coding, its very messy right now. Sorry for that!

Comment: [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17679317/android-google-maps-v2-authentication-error/17684309#17684309) and see if it fixes your issue

Comment: Yeah, some crazy caching going on there. Cleared everything and it just started to work. Still getting the annoying output in logCat though.

Answer (score 1):

[This may be the answer:](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments)

> Note: You cannot inflate a layout into a fragment when that layout includes a fragment. Nested fragments are only supported when added to a fragment dynamically.

And furthermore when playing with nested fragments, use `getChildFragmentManager()`.

In your case it may work (however it should not but you're lucky) on Galaxy S4, but won't work on Xperia Z.

Answer (score 1):

About the NMEA messages, see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48022295/google-maps-system-process-e-locsvc-eng-nmea-i-nmea-cb-line-62/48024019#48024019) to a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48022295/google-maps-system-process-e-locsvc-eng-nmea-i-nmea-cb-line-62) also in StackOverflow.

I'm linking it here to be able to track both answers.

Bottom line: you can safely ignore this log.