# Google Maps API v2 displaying maps only on one device

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

We are using the same API key in the manifest file, which is obtained from the the SHA-1 fingerprint but it is displaying map only on one device(the first device to run it) and not on other devices. We are also using FragmentActivity. So what could be the problem. Please help guys

Comment: are you using the same key in two different programms? if not, what devices do you have +  their android-versions?

Comment: what is your maximum sdk version?

Comment: yes we are using the same key and their android versions are 4.2.2 and 4.3 and maximum sdk version is 17

Comment: check if [this situation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17679317/android-google-maps-v2-authentication-error/17684309#17684309) applies to your case.

Answer (score 0):

Change your max sdk ver to 18 (android 4.3). I suppose this is the device that fail.

An other option - If you use the developers SHA-1 (the one you generate from adb) and you  instaled the app on the devices from the difrent computers computer, then I assume you need to get the SHA-1 fingerprint for the other computer.